# Can Azure Service Bus client connect to ActiveMQ AMQP queues?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Can Microsoft Azure Service Bus 3.1.7 API be used to connect to ActiveMQ AMQP queues, or only to Service Bus AMQP queues?

Answer (score 2):

No. It works only for the SB. [AMQP .NET lite](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite) is the solution to work with SB or any other brokers.