# How to access RabbitMQ using servicebusClient?

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, azureservicebus

Both RabbitMQ and Servicebus ([By adding TransportType=Amqp in connectionstring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-dotnet)) support AMQP. I am using a ServiceBusClient in my C# c ode, how can I make it connect to my RabbitMQ instead?

So what I have for my service bus is something like this:

```
    <add key="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"
value="Endpoint=sb://[namespace].servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=[SAS key];TransportType=Amqp" />
```

What examples of RabbitMQ show are like this with username and password in place:

```
"amqp://" amqp_authority [ "/" vhost ] [ "?" query ]
```

How do I convert in connection string? and how do I replace the SharedAccessKey with username and password?

### Note:

This [question has been asked before 3 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001918/can-azure-service-bus-client-connect-to-activemq-amqp-queues), but since then the framework evolved and as I mentioned is now supporting the AMQP so the answer is not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Though Azure Service Bus uses AMQP 1.0 for its transport, I don't think it could serve as a generic AMQP client itself since the SDK is just a wrapper around the [C# AMQP](https://github.com/Azure/azure-amqp) library with its own API interface.

If the intention is to have the same code base for different brokers, its probably better to use a generic AMQP library like [`amqpnetlite`](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite) instead.